# Jquery onsubmit animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to have a couple of forms such that at one point only one form is seen. After you click next or submit the first form second form should appear and the window should scroll down to the next form. But somehow its not working.

```
function showHide() {
   var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
     div.style.display = '';
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'none';
   }
   }
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form1").submit(function() {
   $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#hidden_div").offset().top},'slow');
       return false;
})
});

 </script>
```

And here's the html part :

```
Some Form elements---

    <div id="button">
                                        <input type="submit"   onclick=showHide(); style="background:#02B98D; padding:8px; border:1px solid black; color:white;  width:20%; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" ></div>
 <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
 <form onsubmit="showHide1(); return false;" method="post" id="form2" >
                                 <section class="widget bottom-tag-line" >
```

Kindly help where I'm going wrong. Here's [a link](http://www.nurturehealthsolutions.com/checkout_new.html) for the same

Comment: A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Can you look it up on [Demo](http://www.nurturehealthsolutions.com/checkout_new.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a small prototype solution for your case:

```js
$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("hidden");
    $($this.attr("action")).removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="#form2" id="form1">
  <input type="text" value="Form 1 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
<form action="#form3" id="form2" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" value="Form 2 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
<form action="save.php" id="form3" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" value="Form 3 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

---

With previous button...

```js
$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("hidden");
    $($this.attr("action")).removeClass("hidden");
  });
  $("input.prev").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("form").addClass("hidden");
    $($(this).data("prev")).removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="#form2" id="form1">
  <input type="text" value="Form 1 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
<form action="#form3" id="form2" class="hidden">
  <input type="button" value="Previous" data-prev="#form1" class="prev" />
  <input type="text" value="Form 2 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
<form action="save.php" id="form3" class="hidden">
  <input type="button" value="Previous" data-prev="#form2" class="prev" />
  <input type="text" value="Form 3 Here" />
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, <input type='submit" /> is inside the <form> tag. I posted only the required code here.

Comment: @Shazam Sorry, can you post your full code, just the form stuff alone?

Comment: @Shazam Actually your code works. Why not keep with jQuery itself and not combine JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: Hi praveen, that worked. However I also require a back button in this case. So that i can toggle through to the prev form page if any details are required to be edited. Thanks!

Comment: @Shazam Sure, but can you not use my code and do it? Or do you want me to do it for you?

Comment: Can you just guide me. I'm not able to do it. @praveen-kumar

Comment: @Shazam Sure buddy, give me an hour. I am in the office. `:(`

Comment: Hi @praveen-kumar , Awaiting your help.

Comment: Hi @Shazam I am on it.